# MaxDB - Strange behaviour when selecting from a CLOB-Row

Tags: linux, sap

I am using "sqlcli" for Linux to write the output of the following query into a file:

> select clob_field from table (...)

in SAPGui (original user input) the contents are displayed as:

```
First line
Second line
Third line
```

in Database Manager the contents are displayed as:

```
First lineSecond lineThird line
```

But in my output-file it is displayed as:

```
First line\rirst line
\nrst Line
Second line \rst line
Second line
\nt line
Second line
Third line
```

My desired output-file should look like:

```
First line\nSecond line\nThird line
```

I am seriously out of ideas of what's happening here or how to fix output. MaxDB also does not seem able to perfom any kind of "CAST"-function.
Replacing "\n" and "\r" doesn't work either, since it does not replace special characters.

Any ideas?